# Why is my ifelse statement converting factors into numbers?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, data-wrangling

I'm having a weird issue with mutating variables in `dplyr`. If I run this code:

```
diamonds %>% 
  select(cut) %>% 
  table()
```

I see this tabulation of the factors in the `diamonds` dataset in R:

```
cut
     Fair      Good Very Good   Premium     Ideal 
     1610      4906     12082     13791     21551
```

However, if I try to change one of the names and leave the rest alone:

```
diamonds %>% 
  mutate(cut.fix = ifelse(cut == "Fair",
                          "Not Fair at All",
                          cut)) %>% 
  select(cut.fix) %>% 
  table()
```

It only changes the "fixed" value and everything else gets turned into numeric values:

```
cut.fix
              2               3               4               5 
           4906           12082           13791           21551 
Not Fair at All 
           1610
```

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Comment: `ifelse()` strips class attributes - this is the documented behavior so it's not the best choice when dealing with non-atomic types of data like factors or date/time variables.  In this case a better choice would be to use `forcats::fct_recode(cut, "Not fair at All" = "Fair" )`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning for `if_else()` is more informative in this case:

```r
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
  select(cut) %>% 
  table()
#> .
#>      Fair      Good Very Good   Premium     Ideal 
#>      1610      4906     12082     13791     21551

diamonds %>% 
  mutate(cut.fix = if_else(cut == "Fair",
                           "Not Fair at All",
                           cut)) %>% 
  select(cut.fix) %>% 
  table()
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `cut.fix = if_else(cut == "Fair", "Not Fair at
#>   All", cut)`.
#> Caused by error in `if_else()`:
#> ! `false` must be a character vector, not a `ordered/factor` object.
```

The `ifelse()` function isn't 'type safe' and it can convert/coerce values in catastrophic ways. Using the dplyr `if_else()` function is safer (errors out in these cases) and you can adjust accordingly, e.g. instead of an ordered factor ("cut") you can convert "cut" to a character:

```r
diamonds %>% 
  mutate(cut.fix = if_else(cut == "Fair",
                           "Not Fair at All",
                           as.character(cut))) %>% 
  select(cut.fix) %>% 
  table()
#> .
#>            Good           Ideal Not Fair at All         Premium       Very Good 
#>            4906           21551            1610           13791           12082
```

This 'works', but as @RitchieSacramento points out, a better solution is to recode the "cut" variable and retain the factor level information, e.g. using `dplyr::recode()`:

```r
diamonds %>% 
  mutate(cut.fix = recode(cut, "Fair" = "Not Fair at All")) %>% 
  select(cut.fix) %>% 
  table()
#> .
#> Not Fair at All            Good       Very Good         Premium           Ideal 
#>            1610            4906           12082           13791           21551
```

Or, the solution from @RitchieSacramento's comment above, using `forcats::fct_recode()`:

```r
diamonds %>%
  mutate(cut.fix = fct_recode(cut, "Not fair at All" = "Fair" )) %>%
  select(cut.fix) %>% 
  table()
#> .
#> Not fair at All            Good       Very Good         Premium           Ideal 
#>            1610            4906           12082           13791           21551
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you and that makes a lot of sense. Thanks as always Jared.

Comment: Thanks @RitchieSacramento, you're absolutely right, recoding the variable is the best solution. In my opinion the best approach is to use `fct_recode()` as you said in your comment above; I've added that example to my answer, but if you would like to write up your own answer I will happily delete mine.

Comment: Thanks guys. That is all very useful to learn. That `fct_recode` option is a very attractive alternative.